# How to embed Openstreetmap's HTML code into Flutteflow?

Tags: android, html, embed, openstreetmap, flutterflow

Unfortunatley, the HTML code that I am trying to embed within flutterflow is not being shown.

I have tried to embedd this HTML code from Openstreetmap:

[View Larger Map](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=13/51.8597/-2.2186)
Unfortunatley, when I went to the widget HTML view at flutterflow and pasted the code nothing appeared, apart from the a single black line (which must have been the border) and the hyper linked text "view larger map" which when you clicked on it did not take you anywhere. Is there something wrong with the code or can you not embed openstreetmap into flutterflow, a app building website.